Unable to connect to O365: The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline
On June 1st my VPS web server (Windows 2016) hosted by Godaddy stopped being able to connect to the Office 365 servers for both SMTP and IMAP (connections work fine from other environments).  The error received is:

The server's SSL certificate could not be validated for the following
reasons:  The server certificate has the following errors:    The
revocation function was unable to check revocation for the
certificate.
The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the
revocation server was offline.
An intermediate certificate has the following errors:    The
revocation function was unable to check revocation for the
certificate.
The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the
revocation server was offline.

The two certificates listed on the exception object are:

Server certificate name: CN=outlook.com, O=Microsoft Corporation,
L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
Root certificate authority name: CN=DigiCert Global Root CA,
OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US

I have found a lot of articles on the web and SO/SF mentioning this error, but I become quickly confused by the terminology (I am a developer with limited networking knowledge) and don't know where to start to troubleshoot this.  I don't know if I merely need to update a cert on my server, or if I have a firewall-type-problem (though I have disabled the Windows firewall for now), or... I don't even know where to start is the real problem!
NOTE: I was able to get past this error by disabling cert revocation checking in my code, but I don't want to leave a hack in place as the final solution.
Any help you can offer is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

It's in the message. You need to be able to connect to the crl url listed in your certificate on HTTP TCP/80. Have you done that?

You may have IP address ranges configured to allow through the firewall, however those lists change and need to be maintained. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/microsoft-365-ip-web-service

@GregAskew - Thank you for your thoughts.  I don't know what you are recommending I do.  All I do is, using code, create a client that connects to the service by passing in a token.  I don't do anything directly with certificates and nothing has changed in my code in the past few months.  To me this seems like something has changed environmentally. Could you elaborate on what your describing?  Thank you!

@GregAskew I'll look at the IP addresses, but I don't think anything changed there.  My server IP is the same and the IP for the site that is connecting to O365 hasn't changed either (though the problem occurs in a command line app I built to test this on the server).

This is a site for system admins. All certificates function in this way and have this requirement. You have to know how this works. We can't walk you through validating the functionality of a certificate that isn't yours.

@GregAskew Any chance you can point me to an article about such things?  Right or wrong, I'm operating as a sysad for this job given that the devs are responsible for managing the server.
